# Derivative and continuity

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

This question relates to AP Calc AB 1997 Question 79:

> Let $f$ be a function such that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2+h)-f(2)}{h}=5$
>
> Which of the following must be true?
>
> 1. $f$ is continuous at $x=2$
> 2. $f$ is differentiable at $2$
> 3. The derivative of $f$ is continuous at $x=2$

I understand that this is $f'(2)=5$ and 1 and 2 are true, but I'm not sure why 3 isn't true (or a counterexample that would make it false) It seems to me that for the derivative of $5$ to exist at $x=2$, the limit of the derivative function at $x=2$ should exist too (and since the derivative at $x=2$ equals the limit of the derivative at $x=2$ then it's continuous)

Answer (score 1):

A counter-example for 3) is $f(x)=5(x-2)+(x-2)^{2} \sin (\frac 1 {x-2})$ for $x \neq 2$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=2$.